# How do I copy class instance to my subclass in python

Tags: python, pyqt, copy, instance, subclass

I have looked at some similar answers but none that seem to address the particular problem I am trying to solve.
Background: I'm using pyqt and QT Designer to design my layout. Currently using pyuic to turn the layout in to a .py file.
In this I have a QListView object.

I would like to extend the QListView class and then copy this particular instance to my new class.

i.e. In my ui.py file I have:

```
self.taskList = QtGui.QListView(self.splitter)
...many other options
self.taskList.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("taskList"))
```

In my mainfile.py i have put a placeholder but image a more methods

```
class MyTaskList(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(arg)
        self._saved_index = self.currentIndex()

    @property
    def saved_index(self):
        return self._saved_index

    @saved_index.setter
    def saved_index(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, QtCore.QModelIndex):
            self._saved_index = index

    def foo(self, thing):
        #do something with thing and self
```

And ideally i would like to take the existing taskList and copy all attributes.
i.e.

```
self.taskList = MyTaskList(self.taskList)
```

note the above obviously won't due to 'arg', However I have tried similar methods that don't seem to copy all the instance attributes, by using various forms of copy in the init and passing the instance to MyNewClass i.e.:

```
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        if isinstance(obj, QtGui.QListView
            self.__dict__ = obj.__dict__.copy()
        #or
            self.__dict__.update(obj.__dict__)
```

Other options that were successful but just looked weird included using types module and monkey patching like below:

```
import types

def foo(self, text):
    print("my object name {} is {}".format(self.objectName(), text))

self.taskList.foo = types.MethodType(foo, self.taskList)
self.taskList.foo('dancing')
```

which prints:

> my object name taskList is dancing

however since I will have a few additional functions and 3 or 4 additional variables this seemed messy.

So what is my best way to achieve this without manually modifying my pyuic generated file each time? I also may want to use many of these methods in another QListView instance that I have.

Edit: There is a way to do this as marked by @ekhumoro using qt designer, which I guess would work in my very particular case (which is awesome to know and didn't even think about that!). However, how could I achieve the same with any class? Imagine in the case above the ui.py is out of my control.

Comment: @ekhumoro, close and very good to know, I wasn't even looking in to it that way as I guess i'm after a different answer (even though that actually solves my particular case). I've updated my answer to be more specific about what i'm after. Although that would work in my particular case and I will try it, i'm also interested to know how I might do it in other cases where the source file is not in my control. Also a learning exercise for me.

Comment: You cannot copy widgets. Please don't waste your time on such hypothetical wild-goose chases. It's not as if there's a shortage of genuine learning exercises available to you.